# "ACPI BIOS ERROR" while dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, bios, acpi, acer

My laptop is Acer Nitro 5 Ryzen 5 Quad Core.
[image]

Comment: Why are you looking at that, instead of the things that are reported 32 seconds later?

Comment: @Vandana have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875173/nmi-watchdog-bug-soft-lockup-cpu2-stuck-for-23s-plymouthd305